# unexpected value in my code and how I fix it

Tags: c++, string

My assignment:

> The teacher has written down the sum of multiple numbers. Pupils should calculate the sum. To make the calculation easier, the sum only contains numbers 1, 2 and 3. Still, that isn't enough for Xenia. She is only beginning to count, so she can calculate a sum only if the summands follow in non-decreasing order. For example, she can't calculate sum 1+3+2+1 but she can calculate sums 1+1+2 and 3+3.
>
> You've got the sum that was written on the board. Rearrange the summons and print the sum in such a way that Xenia can calculate the sum.

> **Input**
> The first line contains a non-empty string s — the sum Xenia needs to count. String s contains no spaces. It only contains digits and characters "+". Besides, string s is a correct sum of numbers 1, 2, and 3. String s is at most 100 characters long.

> **Output**
> Print the new sum that Xenia can count.
>
> #### Examples:
>
> **Input**
>
> ```
> 3+2+1
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> ```
> 1+2+3
> ```

Here is my solution:

```
#include<string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    string su ;
    cin >> su;
    int n, temp ;
    n = su.size();


    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i+=2)
    {
        if (su[i]=='1')
        {
            su[i]-='0';
        }
        else if (su[i]=='2')
        {
            su[i]-='0';
        }
        else if ( su[i]== '3')
        {
            su[i]-='0';
        }
    }

    for (int i =0 ; i <n ; i+=2)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j< n; j+=2 )
        {
            if (su[i]< su [j])
            {
                temp = su[i];
                su[i]=su[j];
                su[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        if(su[i]=='+')
        {
            cout<<su[i];
        }
        else
            cout<<su[i];//this is the line I can't understand why the result like that;
    }


}
```

the problem is when I run the code with input `3+2+1` i expect the output is `1+2+3+` but I get `?+?+?` something like that and I can't understand the reason.

Comment: Use `cout << static_cast<int>(su[i]);` that may tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @anastaciu it's work, nice. but what does this function did?

Comment: It's a C++ style cast it's somewhat similar to `(int)su[i]`, but it's saffer to use.

Comment: Your arithmetic gives you the non printable characters with the codes 1, 2, and 3, [ASCII table](https://thecodewarlock.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/ascii-table-svg.png) you need to cast them to `int` to achieve their integer values.

Comment: @anastaciu I got this, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First doing the s[i] -= '0' is very dangerous as it is a string, you should do int myNum = s[i] - '0' instead and then try storing it inside of the string, because when you do s[i] -= '0' it is never casted into an integer, but it stays char all the time so if you do not cast it to integer, it will go ascii code of '1' - '0' okay that is 1, which symbol has an ascii code of one? Oh it's the SOH character... And it takes the SOH character and put it inside of your string, but you string does not know what SOH is so it goes ???..(just joking, strings do not have emotions). All jokes aside the strange behavior is probably caused by you trying to store an illegal character inside a string. I would convert the '1' - '0' to int first.... Then store it in a string.

Comment: You are right. It's very useful info for me. thanks for helping.